# JQuery Carousel question

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

I have a test website up at http://wms-clients.com/wms2.0/2010/. I am using the jquery carousel built in to my theme. My only problem is that when I advance the slideshow, it skips past some slides, almost as if it's going by twos instead of one slide at a time. I have seen this issue posted in other website forums, but never have gotten a definitive answer. Could someone please take a look and give me their thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In atlantica.js, add a scroll attribute (default is 3) to carousel initialization:

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
            scroll: 1,
            auto: 6,
            wrap: 'last',
            animation: 'slow',
            initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });
```